# Error using Adafruit Feather M0

Tags: arduino-ide, adafruit

I am trying to upload an empty program on the Adafruit feather to see if it connects to my PC. So far, it isn't. I'm running a Windows 10 and I followed this guide:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-wifi-atwinc1500?view=all

But I get this error:

Couldn't find a Board on the selected port. Check that you have the correct port selected.  If it is correct, try pressing the board's reset button after initiating the upload.

And the PORT submenu is greyed out.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I am having the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue I was having, though I have a Gemma.

What worked for me:

- Selecting the correct board under "Tools" -> "Board:" (in your case, the Adafruit Feather 32u4 is probably the one you want)
- Selecting the "USBtinyISP" under "Tools" -> "Programmer:"

Then it was able to upload to the Gemma, after hitting it's reset button twice to get it into a 'programming mode' (I don't know if the feather has such a feature).

If you are still having problems make sure that you have properly set up your arduino IDE for adafruit boards, and just play around with settings (try different programmers).

I don't know why it was so hard finding this info out, and why it is not more visible on the documentation to set these things up. I think I found out the 'hitting reset twice' thing somewhere buried in a forum... I digress, but Adafruit does need to consolidate their documentation to make it clearer.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

A common problem on Windows for people who may be encountering this type of issue is actually having the wrong USB to UART Bridge drivers or none at all. You can download the most up to date ones [here](https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers)